# Checking whether Express Session is expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, expired-sessions

Say node express sessions are saved in an application (meaning they are not necessarily accessed from incoming `req`), how to check whether any of these sessions is expired? What is the proper test?

Comment: Put simply, you would just check whether or not the time between the created timestamp and now is larger than the ttl (or session duration).

Comment: Yeah of course, but what field in the session do I check and how? Do I have to check for nullity?

Comment: I guess that would depend on how the sessions are stored. For example, I store sessions in a database, and routinely remove expired sessions. I guess it all depends on what you are trying to do. Why do you need this information.

Comment: Precisely to remove them from the saving structure. It does not depend how they are saved, the information must be fetched from the session itself.

Answer (score -1):

let's say you have saved User name in session. `req.session.name='pankti'` when you try to get it and if it is undefined then it is expired.`req.session.name == 'undefined'`